# Setting Datepicker with JQuery Changes Both the Date and Format

Tags: jquery, razor, datepicker

I have a cshtml page that has a datepciker:

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" id="expiry" type="text" placeholder="dd-mmm-yyyy" value="">
```

It gets initialized with:

```
$('body').on('focus', ".datepicker", function () {
   $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
});
```

When you pick a date it works fine, so if I pick Mar 18 it looks like "18-MAR-2020".

But if I use jquery:

```
var $datepicker = $("#expiry");
$datepicker.datepicker();
$datepicker.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mmm-yyyy' });
$datepicker.datepicker('setDate', "18-MAR-2020");
```

It puts this in the value: "09/25/2014".

So both the date and format are wrong. Then if I use the datepicker to choose a different date, it stays in the incorrect format.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

First you need to format with this line:

```
$("#expiry").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
```

Then you need to set the date in this format: "03/18/2020"

Which is horrifying, but it works